# Does hijacking execve() make it temporarily unavailable?

Tags: linux, system-calls, kernel-module

I have an interest in modifying Linux for my own purposes through hijacking system calls. I have managed to successfully hijack `open()`, `ioctl()`, and the system calls used for manipulating extended attributes. I am trying to hijack `execve()` with:

```
asmlinkage int (*real_execve)(const char __user *,
                              const char __user *const __user *,
                              const char __user *const __user *);

asmlinkage int hijacked_execve(const char __user *filename,
                               const char __user *const __user *argv, 
                               const char __user *const __user *envp) {
    return real_execve(filename, argv, envp);
}
```

by [modifying the system call table](http://syprog.blogspot.com/2011/10/hijack-linux-system-calls-part-iii.html). Upon inserting the kernel module, the terminal just hangs. If I type in a command and press enter, the terminal just acts like a text editor that won't accept backspaces or react to Ctrl+X or Ctrl+C, looking like:

```
main@vm:~/hijack_execve$ sudo insmod hijack_execve.ko
[sudo] password for main:
main@vm:~/hijack_execve$ <any command>
^C^X
```

Strangely, I can hijack `mmap()` so long as it maintains the same form as above, only passing the parameters on to the real `mmap()`. Anyone have any idea as to what could be going wrong here? I'm wondering if the process of hijacking `execve()` makes it unavailable during the time the system call table is being modified, and that during this time `execve()` is needed to complete the operation.

Comment: Tried using a debugger to observe what is really going on?  With complete source to everything (linux kernel, hijack module, glibc, and shell) you should have a reasonably nice debug experience.  (It may help to recompile things with `-g` option to generate debug information)

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't know how to do debugging and I can't see how I could use a debugger (I know enough to understand that a debugger runs with the code) since my module would just bring everything, including the debugger, to a halt.

Comment: Kernel debuggers run on a second computer, exactly to avoid that issue.  (Or the kernel and module being debugged can run inside a virtual machine, allowing the host to run the debugger without interruption)

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm already running Linux inside VMware Player and I don't have a second computer.

Comment: Then you're in great shape, a "second computer" is as close as a copy of the virtual machine, plus [configuring VMware to simulate a high-speed serial connection between the two](http://stackframe.blogspot.com/2007/04/debugging-linux-kernels-with.html).

Comment: Or see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2255666/103167

Comment: Actually, link above describes a method other than serial port (and probably won't work with VMware Player).  For serial port see http://jaredrobinson.com/blog/using-the-2626-linux-kernel-debugger-kgdb-with-vmware/